# Mapping mysql database to owl

Tags: mapping, semantic-web, ontology, protege

I would like to create an ontology for MySQL database using protege, after that, I would like to map the database with the ontology.

Can anyone help me and send me any resources or example?

Answer (score 1):

To map a relational database to an RDF dataset, you should create an R2RML mapping as described at https://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/#dfn-r2rml-mapping.